# How do i fix the gap at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css, margin

I am trying to get the grey box to the top of the page.

Any code snippets would be appreciated.

```html
<style> * { font-family: "arial" }</style> 

<h1 class="small" style="background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); background-image: none; background-origin: padding-box; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-repeat: repeat; background-size: auto; box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(229, 229, 229); font-family: inherit; font-size: 22px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px; orphans: 2; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 15px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;"></h1><span style="display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">
</span><div class="field" style="background-attachment: scroll; background-clip: border-box; background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); background-image: none; background-origin: padding-box; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-repeat: repeat; background-size: auto; border-bottom-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-image-outset: 0; border-image-repeat: stretch; border-image-slice: 100%; border-image-source: none; border-image-width: 1; border-left-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); border-left-style: solid; border-left-width: 1px; border-right-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: 1px; border-top-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px; orphans: 2; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;"><br></div
```

Comment: Nobody can read that code, you need to use a formatted version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please format the code properly and why is all but one style inline?  You've given everything class names so all the styles should be applied to the classes in either the `<style>` tag or in a separate CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser's User-Agent adds browser specific styles.

You will need to override these in either the `<style>` tag or in an external stylesheet.

So to resolve your issue you need to add the following code;

```
body { margin: 0; }
h1 { margin-top: 0; }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193858/discussion-on-answer-by-scottieg-how-do-i-fix-the-gap-at-the-top-of-the-page).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding style margin-top:0 to body and h1 tags